# Arbitrary number of assignments (lists (of numbers)) converted into single list

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to combine a matrice into a single list. I've tried to wrap my head around tree traversals / 0(n*expression) stuff that i keep finding via search. I really don't think this problem is as hard as i'm making it out to be!?

```
# example of what output should be 
# ('147','258','369')

m = [1,2,3]
n = [4,5,6]
o = [7,8,9]

def myFun(*args):
    return [zip(args[x][i]) for x in args for i in args[x]]

print(myFun(m,n,o))
```

For future reference, would using a map be a smarter approach for handling matrices in this manor? I've read that maps can apply a function to every element, as such i was skeptical about using such a method and getting additional output (e.g. [('471','582','693', and so on)]

Comment: Do you really want the output to be tuple of strings?

Comment: I may be a bit confused, i'm sorry i'm still learning... Basically when i call print(myFun(m,n,o)) it should return a 147, 258, 369

Comment: To get that output from `print()`, `myfunc()` would need to return the string `'147, 258, 369'`. If it returned `(147, 258, 369)` or `[147, 258, 369]`, which are both sequences of integers, the output would have a pair of parentheses or brackets in it, too.

Comment: so then i would have to include an additional for loop to iter the newlist formed by A.R.S answer - which should print a for x in list..? Or are you suggesting that i sit down and re-think how to approach this problem because i've gone astray and am making it more complicated than it need be?

Comment: No, not necessarily. Actually, A.R.S.'s answer -- which was written before my question/comment -- returns a sequence of integers, not the strings shown in your question. If that's OK, the answer could be simplified a bit to `return [reduce(lambda x,y: x*10+y, x) for x in zip(*args)]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What this comes down to is transposing the matrix. This can be done with

```
zip(*args)
```

Once we have this, we can join each row to form a new integer, and place these values in a new list:

```
def myFun(*args):
    return [int(''.join(map(str, l))) for l in zip(*args)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
m = [1,2,3]
n = [4,5,6]
o = [7,8,9]

a = zip(m, n, o)  # [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]

b = [''.join(map(str, x)) for x in a] # ['147', '258', '369']
```

Comment: i really don't know much about python but based off what i can read is that the arguments are already supplied when you call zip(m,n,o)... If you altered that to be zip(args)? (if i'm not retarded at least.. then you should be able to get the output your looking for?? Then again, i don't really think you can assign multi-variables to a single int... So you'd probably have to do something more pythonic and long hand (for this... for that.. if this.. for that.. for blah... do: a.append(zip(*args))?? I think that's how it would go atleast..?